# Run application after successful install

Tags: inno-setup

How to make check box that allow user to run application  after installation?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check the `postinstall` flag in the `[Run]` section, see the documentation at https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_runsection.htm#postinstall

Answer (score 47):

There you go:

---

under `[Run]`:

```
Filename: {app}\{cm:AppName}.exe; Description: {cm:LaunchProgram,{cm:AppName}}; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

---

under `[CustomMessages]`:

```
AppName=mySoftwaresNiceName
LaunchProgram=Start mySoftware after finishing installation
```

Comment: How do i tell to do : AppName.exe argument1 argument2 ?

Comment: Ask a separate question please

Comment: @Akku I provide my app name in AppName but it is giving me error that my player name is not defined

Comment: @Mohammad This question is not about self defined constants, so write a new question if you have one, and provide more information about your problem.

Answer (score 15):

Add Filename to Run Section with Flag postinstall.

Example for Copy&Paste:

```
[Run]
// User selected... these files are shown for launch after everything is done
Filename: {app}\README.TXT; Description: View the README file; Flags: postinstall shellexec skipifsilent
Filename: {app}\APP.EXE; Description: Run Application; Flags: postinstall nowait skipifsilent unchecked
```

Answer (score 7):

To make the checkbox, create a task:

```
[Tasks]
Name: StartAfterInstall; Description: Run application after install
```

and bind it to "run" action:

```
[Run]
Filename: {app}\{#exe}; Flags: shellexec skipifsilent nowait; Tasks: StartAfterInstall
```

where {#exe} is the name of exe-file