# How can I move tasks section after installing section in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

Note that I am new to Inno Setup. Currently I have the following:

`Installation language selection (1) -> Select additional tasks (2) -> Ready to install (3) -> Installing (4) -> Click finish to exit Setup. (5)`

What I want to achieve is to have user prompted for `Additional tasks (2)` after `Installing (4)`.
I have `Create a desktop shortcut` and `Launch application` checkboxes on Additional tasks.

Here is the script that I use for generating a setup (with various things replaced with mock data as I cannot disclose them).

```
#define MyAppName "My App"
#define MyAppExeName "MyApp.exe"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "MyCompanyName"

[Setup]
AppId={{someId}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
DefaultDirName={autopf}\{#MyAppName}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
OutputBaseFilename=My App
SetupIconFile=C:\MyApp\logo.ico
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
WizardStyle=modern

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"
Name: StartAfterInstall; Description: Launch application; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"
Name: "ukrainian"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Ukrainian.isl"

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\myuser\MyApp\bin\Release\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs

[Icons]
Name: "{userdesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: {app}\{#MyAppExeName}; Flags: shellexec skipifsilent nowait; Tasks: StartAfterInstall
```

Update:

Changing my `[Run]` section to this:

`Filename: {app}\{#MyAppExeName}; Flags: shellexec skipifsilent nowait; AfterInstall: CreateIcon`

and adding the `[Code]` section as follows:

```pascal
[Code]

procedure CreateIcon;
var
  IconFileName: string;
begin
  IconFileName := ExpandConstant('{commondesktop}\DashBoard.lnk');

  CreateShellLink(
    IconFileName, '',
    ExpandConstant('{app}\{#MyAppExeName}'),
    '', ExpandConstant('{app}'),
    ExpandContant('{app}\logo.ico'), 0, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
end;
```

did not add a checkbox to the last setup step.

I tried adding `ChangesAssociations=yes` to the end of my `[Setup]` section with no checkbox added either.

After that I thought I could use the same method as with which I've managed to add a checkbox to launch an application on the last setup step.

So, trying to add a second checkbox like this:

```
[Run]
Filename: {app}\{cm:AppName}.exe; Description: {cm:LaunchProgram,cm:AddShortcut,{cm:AppName}}; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent

[CustomMessages]
AppName=MyApp
LaunchProgram=Start MyApp after finishing installation
AddShortcut=Add desktop shortcut
```

leaves me with only one checkbox instead of two.

Might I just say that before adding a second checkbox it was like so:

```
[Run]
Filename: {app}\{cm:AppName}.exe; Description: {cm:LaunchProgram,{cm:AppName}}; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent

[CustomMessages]
AppName=MyApp
LaunchProgram=Start MyApp after finishing installation
```

If any further information is needed - let me know.

Update:

Here is latest version of script:

```
#define MyAppName "MyApp"
#define MyAppExeName "MyApp.exe"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "MyCompany"

[Setup]
AppId={{678F2A68-E028-46F0-A18C-0A47135A98E8}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
DefaultDirName={autopf}\{#MyAppName}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
OutputBaseFilename=MyApp
SetupIconFile=C:\Users\myuser\Projects\MyApp\logo.ico
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
WizardStyle=modern

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"
Name: "ukrainian"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Ukrainian.isl"

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\myuser\Projects\MyApp\bin\Debug\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs

[Icons]
Name: "{userdesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"

[Run]
Filename: {app}\{cm:AppName}.exe; Description: {cm:LaunchProgram,{cm:AppName}}; Flags: postinstall skipifsilent;
Filename: {app}\{cm:AppName}.exe; Description: {cm:AddShortcut,{cm:AppName}}; Flags: postinstall skipifsilent;

[CustomMessages]
AppName=MyApp
LaunchProgram=Start MyApp after finishing installation
AddShortcut=Add shortcut to desktop

[Code]

procedure CreateIcon;
var
  IconFileName: string;
begin
  IconFileName := ExpandConstant('{commondesktop}\MyApp.lnk');

  CreateShellLink(
    IconFileName, '',
    ExpandConstant('{app}\{#MyAppExeName}'),
    '', ExpandConstant('{app}'),
    ExpandConstant('{app}\logo.ico'), 0, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
end;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optionally running an application after an installation has finished is easy. See:
[Inno Setup - How to create checkboxes at finished page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42836022/850848) or
[Run application after successful install](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3767227/850848)

---

Creating the desktop shortcut is more complicated. An easy way (from the perspective of Inno Setup script) is to "outsource" the shortcut creation – to the application itself (via a command-line parameter) or to some script (e.g. PowerShell).  And then you can run that application/script the same was as the application above.

If you want the installer itself to create the shortcut, you would have to hack it like shown here:
[Running script code (adding a registry key) instead of executable in Run entry in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34007625/850848)

A code to create a shortcut in code is here:
[Create desktop link Icon after the Run section of Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44076985/850848)